# Is there any way to make a custom DialogFragment cancelable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a DialogFragment which uses a custom view from xml. Calling `dialog?.setCancelable(true)` from `onViewCreated` does nothing. Is there any way I can use the default cancel button or do I have to implement a custom cancel button in my view?

Comment: What do you want to do with this fragment? Do you want the fragment to be shown? As documentation instructs "setCanceled - Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key."

Comment: can you share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need :

```
getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Call it in `onCreateView`

If you want to dismiss it call `dismiss();`